# Designing UI for trading game in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a game that involves trading with other players. I have the engine down, but my UI is not coming along nearly as well. Among other things, I want to create...

- plus/minus buttons that are either arrows or circles, with plus being red and minus being green. I saw options for adding bitmaps, but I read they can only be monochrome. Also saw no way to reshape button into anything other than a rectangle.
- clickable tiles, representing the players to trade with. Again, I could not find any way to do this with buttons.

So far, I've been using canvas rectangles/ovals/polygons, binding tags to them, and binding callbacks to the tags. Wondering if there are smarter ways.

I'm new to UI design, and I'm not sure whether I can't physically do these things with Tkinter and should choose another graphics package, or whether I am just a noob.

Comment: You can add an image to a button, and they don't need to be monochrome. For all the other issues, using any GUI toolkit that is intended for building Desktop applications is a bad idea for what you are doing. If you prefer to stay in Python, then something like pyglet (http://www.pyglet.org/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is that (AFAIK) you can only make buttons into rectangles. So if I wanted a circular button, or one in the shape of an arrow, I would have to manually draw it. Or create an image in a canvas.

Comment: That is right, and that is where the second part of the comment applies: it is a bad choice to go with Tkinter and related GUI toolkits for the task.

Comment: Would pyGame be a smarter move?

Comment: Pygame, pyglet, and others, are better tools for what you are doing. I wouldn't use pygame myself because I don't have good performance with it, but maybe it could serve you well.

Comment: What worries my about pyglet is whether it is stable. It looks like it's still in alpha.